# Total merging search optimization

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, optimization, recursion

Assume there is a vector VA of size N, and each element is another vector of type T.  There is an operation on type T and returning a new value of type T, i.e., `bool merge(T a, T b, T &ret);`. If a and c can be merged, then store the result in `ret` and return true; otherwise, return false. The merge operation is reflective and transitive.

A solution is found if either:

1. ∃ x<sub>0</sub>, x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>N-1</sub>. merge(VA[0][x<sub>0</sub>], VA[1][x<sub>1</sub>], merge(VA[2][x<sub>2</sub>], ..., merge(VA[N-2][x<sub>N-2</sub>],VA[N-1][x<sub>N-1</sub>], ret)...));
2. any elements from N-1 (**not N**) sub-vectors can be merged (pick any N-1 with exactly one exception).

For example:
VA is of size 3. Element a can be merged with Element b with the result c. Element c can be merged with Element d with the result e.

- VA[0] = {a}
- VA[1] = {b, q}
- VA[2] = {d, r}

All solutions in the above example are: {a,b}, {a,d}, {b,d}, {a,b,d}.

The task is to find all solution in the given vector VA.

My C++ code is:

```
void findAll(unsigned int step, unsigned int size, const T pUnifier, int hole_id) {
  if(step == size) printOneResult(pUnifier);
  else {
    _path[step] = -1;
    findAll(step + 1, pUnifier, step);
  }
  std::vector<T> vec = VA[step];
  for(std::vector<T>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it < vec.end(); it++) {
    T nextUnifier();
    if( merge( *it, pUnifier, nextUnifier )) {
       _path[lit_id] = it->getID();
       findAll(step + 1, nextUnifier, hole_id);
    }
  }
}
```

The code contains recursive calls; however, it is not tail recursive. It is running slowly in practice. In reality, the size of VA is possibly hundreds and each sub-vector size is of hundreds, too. I'm wondering whether it can be optimized.

Thank you very much.

Comment: C++ won't optimize your tail recursive calls (at least not according to the standard) so that's a minor concern.  Have you looked in your for loop?  I imagine that's where most of the time is spent because your iterations can stack up.  You're looping and recursing into possibly another loop with recursion, ad infinitum.  If you could cut down on some of the looping, that could net you a big gain in cycles saved.  Not saying it's possible (I haven't looked at it closely enough), but it's worth researching.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is hard to cut down some looping. It depends on ordering, but it is hard to find a good sorting heuristic. Maybe, I can consider how to memorize some partial results.

Comment: You could also see if there's anything you can do to your data before it goes into the findAll so that you can take some shortcuts.

Comment: Is your return type `bool` or `void`? It can't be both, and if it's the former, you're missing a return statement.

Comment: Sorry, for the recursive function, the return type is void. I just remove the ambiguity.

Comment: @RonaldBarzell In GCC, -O3 will do the tail recursion optimization. Do you have some ideas about how to make it a nice tail recursion?

Comment: @ildjarn: bool is for merge function while void is for findAll recursive function

Comment: @TianyiLiang I knew GCC did tail recursion in some circumstances years ago, but I didn't realize it was across the board.  Wow.  Isn't your code already tail recursive, since it doesn't return anything anyway?  The only change I'd recommend is to find a non-destructive update for _path and treat it as an accumulator in the findAll parameter list, so you can restrict all changes to the scope of findAll.

Comment: @RonaldBarzell it is not tail recursive at all. The recursive call is inside the loop, and there are two calls.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your code correctly, you're performing a (recursive) brute-force search. This is not efficient, since you're given some information about your search space.

I think a good candidate here would be the [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm). You could use the current greatest-chain size as the heuristic, or perhaps even the sum of the squares of the chain sizes.

Comment: it is really hard to prune the search space, and in fact almost every search path is useful. Therefore, I'm thinking to optimize the recursive structure itself.

Answer (score -1):

To improve your code, as you use vectors, you should use the [] operator, with a `int` counter instead of simple iterators, that are much much slower.
You can improve it even more by minimising the function calls i either of your loops, like previously stacking the values you will use.
Since you didn't explained what really was a T_VEC, i coudln't not wrote the complete iterator-free version, but this should already be a great plus regarding speed.

Comment: -1 In release builds you would be extremely hard-pressed to find a modern standard library implementation whose `std::vector<>` iterators have any overhead whatsoever.

Comment: Based on what evidence? Last I checked, iterators had a slight edge over indexing...

Comment: For clearance, `T_VEC` is `std::vector<T>`, `T` is some complicated data structure(just consider it as a template). It is better to use a iterator than an `int` counter. Based on my previous testing, I don't see any speedup by using an `int` counter, on the other side, an iterator is more convenient.

Comment: Well, it's true that the difference between iterators and index access speed depends on the compiler and optimisations, my bad here.
But you can at least reduce execution time by removing useless calls to vec.end() by saving it in another iterator and comparing them. If the loop is large, it should be significant.

Comment: @tsukasan No, I don't think so. `vec.end()` returns an address, just like an `int`. The overhead is too small. You may try a loop for a million times. There will not be any difference.